# How to interpret Universal Quantifiers next to each other?

Tags: first-order-logic

Lets say for example that we have $\forall x \forall y(P(x,y) \lor Q(x,y))$.

In terms of looping does this mean that we pick one x and then loop over the y. Once we reach the last y, we increase x and loop again. Or does it mean we loop over them together increasing simultaneously?

In other words if we have $x,y \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ does that mean we would end up with $$P(1,1) \lor Q(1,1)\\P(1,2) \lor Q(1,2)\\P(1,3) \lor Q(1,3)\\P(1,4) \lor Q(1,4)\\P(2,1) \lor Q(2,1)\\P(2,2) \lor Q(2,2)\\...$$
or
$$P(1,1) \lor Q(1,1)\\P(2,2) \lor Q(2,2)\\P(3,3) \lor Q(3,3)\\P(4,4) \lor Q(4,4)$$

I figured by default that it would be the former, but I am just double checking. And if its the former in what scenario would we have the latter?

Comment: If you want just the last four statements, just write $\forall x(P(x,x) \lor Q(x,x)).$

Answer (score 1):

That's right, it is the first one. The variables $x$ and $y$ have "nothing to do with each other". After all, in a different situation $x$ could e.g. always be an integer while $y$ could always be a set, and then the second interpretation would not even make sense (let alone be correct).

Answer (score 1):

Let’s do a simpler example. Suppose we have $\forall x\forall y \ P(x,y)$, and suppose our domain is $\{1,2\}$

Then $\forall x \forall y \ P(x,y)$ means that for any $x$ that you pick, it has to be true that $\forall y \ P(x,y)$ . Given this domain, that therefore means that both

$\forall y \ P(1,y)$

and

$\forall y \ P(2,y)$

are true.

But for $\forall y \ P(1,y)$ to be true in thus domain, we must have that

$P(1,1)$

as well as

$P(1,2)$

Likewise, for $\forall y \ P(2,y)$ to be true, you need to have both

$P(2,1)$

and

$P(2,2)$

In sum, you need all of $P(1,1), P(1,2), P(2,1), P(2,2)$ to be true, so it is like the first option you indicate.

Note that this way of thinking about it can also nicely demonstrate the difference between claims like $\forall x \exists y \ P(x,y)$, $\exists x \forall y \ P(x,y)$, and $\exists y \forall x \ P(x,y)$:

$\forall x \exists y \ P(x,y)$ means that you need:

$\exists y \ P(1,y)$ and $\exists y \ P(2,y)$

which means you need:

$P(1,1)$ or $P(1,2)$, as well as $P(2,1)$ or $P(2,2)$

Or, in terms of propositional logic: ($P(1,1) \lor P(1,2)) \land (P(2,1) \lor P(2,2))$

And if we think of $P(x,y)$ as the claim that a $1$ is put in $(x,y)$ in a 2-dimensional grid of $1$'s and $0$'s:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
&1&2\\
\hline
1&0/1&0/1\\
2&0/1&0/1\\
\end{array}

then we see that ($P(1,1) \lor P(1,2)) \land (P(2,1) \lor P(2,2))$ means that we have at least one $1$ in the first row, and at least one $1$ in the second row, e.g. something like:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
&1&2\\
\hline
1&0&1\\
2&1&0\\
\end{array}

On the other hand, $\exists x \forall y \ P(x,y)$ means that you need (I'll go straight to propositional logic notation):

$\forall y \ P(1,y) \lor \forall y \ P(2,y)$

and that means you need:

$(P(1,1) \land P(1,2))  \lor (P(2,1) \land P(2,2))$

and in terms of our grid, that means we need at least one row with all $1$'s, e.g:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
&1&2\\
\hline
1&1&1\\
2&0&0\\
\end{array}

Finally, in the given domain, $\exists y \forall x \ P(x,y)$ means:

$\forall x \ P(x,1) \lor \forall x \ P(x,2)$

and thus:

$(P(1,1) \land P(2,1)) \lor (P(1,2) \land P(2,2))$

and that means we need at least one column with all $1$'s, e.g:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
&1&2\\
\hline
1&0&1\\
2&0&1\\
\end{array}

Note that in each of the last three specific tables, exactly one of the last three claims is true, showing that they all mean distinctly different things

Of course, cycling back to $\forall x \forall y \ P(x,y)$: this would mean that all entries in the table are a $1$. So again, the first option you describe is the correct way to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is always an implied set of parentheses around the statement directly following each quantifier. So $\forall x \forall y P(x, y)$ is actually $\forall x \left(\forall y \left( P(x, y) \right) \right)$, which unfurls to:

> For every value of $x$, the statement $Q(x)$ is true, where $Q(x)$ is the statement "for every value of $y$, the statement $P(x, y)$ is true".

This clearly means that you have to check that whatever value of $x$ you choose, the statement $P(x, y)$ has to be true for every possible value of $y$, so it's not just the cases where $x = y$.

In the case where all of your quantifiers are universal ones (i.e. $\forall$s), it doesn't matter much which way around you write them. However, when you have existential quantifiers in there (i.e. some $\exists$s), changing the order also changes the meaning of the statement. For example, $\forall x \exists y P(x, y)$ is equivalent to $\forall x (\exists y (P(x, y))$, which becomes:

> For every value of $x$, the statement $Q(x)$ is true, where $Q(x)$ is the statement "there exists a value $y$ such that the statement $P(x, y)$ is true".

Whereas $\exists y \forall x P(x, y)$ or $\exists y (\forall x (P(x, y)))$ is:

> There is a value $y$ that makes the statement $Q(y)$ true, where $Q(y)$ is the statement "for every value of $x$, the statement $P(x, y)$ is true".

Notice that in the former case the value of $y$ may depend on $x$ (so you pick a value of $x$, and having done so you can find a value of $y$ that makes $P(x, y)$ true), but in the latter there exists some value of $y$ that makes $P(x, y)$ true regardless of $x$, which is a much stronger claim. For example, $\forall x \exists y (x + y = 0)$ is true across the real numbers (every real number has a negative), but $\exists y \forall x (x + y = 0)$ is *not* true, since that says there's a universal value of $y$ that you can add to any number to make 0. On the other hand, $\exists y \forall x (xy = x)$ *is* true - there's a universal value of $y$ that can make $xy = x$ true for every value of $x$ (that value is $y = 1$).